# Understanding async in React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm using axios to return the details of a Pokemon:

```
class PokeDetails extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { pokemon: null }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                pokemon: res.data
            });
        }).catch((err) => { console.log('Axios Poke Details error: ', err) });
    }
    render(){
        const {pokemon} = this.state;
        const pokeCard = pokemon ? (
            <div className="poke-details">
               <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={`${pokemon.name} front`}/>
               <h3 className="card-title">{pokemon.name}</h3>
            </div>
            ) : (
            <div className="center">Loading Pokemon...</div>)
        return(
            <div className="container">
                {pokeCard}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PokeDetails
```

I want to display the pokemon types, which is an array that has a length of 1 or 2 depending on the pokemon. So I thought:

```
render(){
   const {pokemon} = this.state
   const listTypes = pokemon.types.map((type) => { <li>{type.name}</li> });
}
```

...and render listTypes in a `ul` in `const pokeCard`. When I do this I get an error saying pokemon is null. Shouldn't this not happen because of the ternary operator rendering the pokeCard?

Comment: In the updated code where your `render` has only two lines, there is no conditional operator anywhere? To make the `.types.map(…)` call conditional, you need to move it inside the ternary expression.

Comment: Looks like you're calling `pokemon.types.map()` regardless of `pokemon` being null; if you want this to be affected by the ternary op, you need to use `<ul>pokemon.types.map((type) => { <li>{type.name}</li> })</ul>` inside the JSX.

Comment: Remote data is better kept in cache and not in the state, did you try using useSWR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `componentDidMount` is called *after* the initial render. So on the initial render, `pokemon` is `null`. That is why accessing `pokemon.types` fails.

You need to access `pokemon.types` only when `pokemon` is not `null`. Just move the code where you `.map()` over the `pokemon.types` inside the ternary operator.

```
const pokeCard = pokemon ? (
  <div className="poke-details">
    <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={`${pokemon.name} front`} />
    <h3 className="card-title">{pokemon.name}</h3>
    <ul>
     {pokemon.types.map(({ type }) => (
       <li key={type.name}>{type.name}</li>
     ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
) : (
  <div className="center">Loading Pokemon...</div>
);
```

#### Demo:

```js
class PokeDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pokemon: null };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          pokemon: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Axios Poke Details error: ", err);
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { pokemon } = this.state;
    const pokeCard = pokemon ? (
      <div className="poke-details">
        <img
          src={pokemon.sprites.front_default}
          alt={`${pokemon.name} front`}
        />
        <h3 className="card-title">{pokemon.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {pokemon.types.map(({ type }) => (
            <li key={type.name}>{type.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="center">Loading Pokemon...</div>
    );
    return <div className="container">{pokeCard}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PokeDetails />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This worked. I'm unfamiliar with JSK: are you de-structuring inside the map() function by putting type inside curly brackets? Also unsure why wrapping the <li> in brackets helped, earlier I was just returning the result to no avail.

Comment: _are you de-structuring inside the map() function by putting type inside curly brackets?_ - yes, `types` array contains objects which have a `type` property which is an object with the data you want to display. _Also unsure why wrapping the <li> in brackets helped_ - you were not returning anything from the `.map()` method. When arrow functions have curly brackets, you need to use `return` keyword to return anything from an arrow function. If you omit curly brackets, you can return something implicitly without writing the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pokemon` before its detail get fetched from service, try like given:

```
const listTypes = pokemon && pokemon.types.map((type) => { <li>{type.name}</li> });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rome data is better kept in cache, in case it gets shared between componenets in different levels.
I reproduced your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = async (...args) => {
  const res = await fetch(...args);

  return res.json();
};

function PokeDetails() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1', fetcher);

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        data.map((pokemon) => {
          return (
            <div className='poke-details'>
              <img
                src={pokemon.sprites.front_default}
                alt={`${pokemon.name} front`}
              />
              <h3 className='card-title'>{pokemon.name}</h3>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Some loading content</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PokeDetails;
```

you can check [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/why-you-should-be-separating-your-server-cache-from-your-ui-state-1585a9ae8336) to get a clear idea.